# Wrong highlights in custom TextToSpeechService

Tags: java, android, audio, text-to-speech, wav

I extended TextToSpeechService from the Android API's to make my own custom TTS Service. The TTS service gets info from a TTS server. The server gives me an audio buffer with a few lists that contain the start positions of the highlights and the timings for those. The problem is that my highlights are placed too early on the next word that the TTS engine is about to speak. I can't seem to find what causes this. I think that the `audioPositionMillis`might be wrong but as far as i know the calculation is correct. I think the audioPositionMillis is around 700 milliseconds too fast. I'm overlooking something small

```
   @Override
    protected synchronized void onSynthesizeText(SynthesisRequest request, SynthesisCallback callback) {

        // Note that we call onLoadLanguage here since there is no guarantee
        // that there was a prior call to this function.
        int load = onLoadLanguage(request.getLanguage(), request.getCountry(), request.getVariant());

        // We might get requests for a language we don't support - in which case
        // we error out early before wasting too much time.
        if (load == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            callback.error();
            return;
        }

        String ttsText = request.getCharSequenceText().toString();
        final int speechRate = mapSpeechRate(request.getSpeechRate());
        TtsParams ttsParams = new TtsParams(ttsText, currentVoice, speechRate, VOLUME,
                TIME_BETWEEN_SENTENCES_MILLIS, BIT_RATE, TtsParams.Format.WAV);

        try {
            TtsInfo data = null;
            Response<TtsInfo> response = serviceManager.getTtsInfo(ttsParams); //Synchronous call because methods executed on the synthesisCallback need to be called on the synth thread.
            if(response != null){
                data = response.body();
            }

            if(data == null){
                callback.error();
                return;
            }

            //Response does not make any sense to me, we modify its data
            List<Integer> wordPositionsMs = data.getAudioPos();
            List<Integer> wordStartPositions = data.getCharPos();
            List<Integer> wordLengths = data.getCharCount();

            wordStartPositions.add(0, 0);
            wordStartPositions.remove(wordStartPositions.size() - 1);

            wordPositionsMs.add(0, 102); //First word always starts at 102ms according to the docs
            wordPositionsMs.remove(wordStartPositions.size() - 1);

            callback.start(SAMPLING_RATE_HZ, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, CHANNEL_COUNT);
            int maxBufferSize = callback.getMaxBufferSize();
            byte[] audioBuffer = Base64.decode(data.getByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            int offset = 0;
            while (offset < audioBuffer.length) {
                int bytesToWrite = Math.min(maxBufferSize, audioBuffer.length - offset);
                if(callback.audioAvailable(audioBuffer, offset, bytesToWrite) != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    callback.error();
                    return;
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    long audioPositionMillis = Math.round(offset / ((SAMPLING_RATE_HZ/1000D) * CHANNEL_COUNT * (BIT_DEPTH/8D)));
                    int wordIndex = -1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < wordPositionsMs.size(); i++) {
                        if (audioPositionMillis > wordPositionsMs.get(i)) {
                            wordIndex++;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (wordIndex > -1) {
                        int wordStart = wordStartPositions.get(wordIndex);
                        int wordLength = wordLengths.get(wordIndex);
                        callback.rangeStart(-1, wordStart, wordStart + wordLength);
                    }
                }

                offset += bytesToWrite;
            }
            callback.done();
        } catch (IOException | NoNetworkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            callback.error();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed -1 as the markerInFrames parameter to the rangeStart callback method, which caused this.

Solution:

```
callback.rangeStart((int)(offset/(BIT_DEPTH/8D)), wordStart, wordStart + wordLength);
```